# Shopify - Passing object value {{ order.order_number }} by URL to prefill a form

Tags: javascript, html, shopify, liquid

This takes in a few questions - I am unsure how to pass values on Shopify from one page to another.

In my case what I want to do:

1. When a customer orders a certain product and checkouts, it triggers the additional script I have on my checkout page settings.
2. This redirect them to a new page on the site, with a form in it

This all works fine, but I want to ensure when the customer fills that form in, I know who it came from. Carrying their order number {{ order.order_number }} (or email address) to the page and using that value to prefill a hidden form input is what I want to do. Is this done with liquid objects, or can it simply be captured from the output on the checkout page in html?

I have set up the page with the hidden fields, but I have no idea how to capture the order number and carry it across to this new page.

Thanks for the help

C

---

Edit - passing the value by URL is quite easy in the end. Using the Objects in Shopify (https://help.shopify.com/themes/liquid/objects) I can carry the {{ order.name }} from the order page as part of the URL:

/pages/check-out-form?order={{ order.name | url_param_escape }}

Note: these objects only output if they are either global, or page appropriate e.g the order objects will only work on order.pagenameexaple pages

Comment: You can pass it as a GET parameter or use a cookie to set and get it afterwards.

Comment: You could use the sessionStorage API https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage ... Unless you're opening a new tab, then maybe localStorage API https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage

Comment: Also, how does this question relate to Ruby on Rails?

Comment: Thanks Sam/Drip: (wrong tag removed for Ruby)

As a beginner, I can't figure out how to take the URL variable (as per edit above) and simply putting it into the name[body] field or otherwise.

Comment: @ShopifyUserG are you saying you were able to pass the parameters to the page (in the URL), but you don't know how to access the URL parameters once on the page? If that's the case try `window.location.search`.

Comment: @ShopifyUserG Why not put some query strings in the redirect URL and use JS to parse them and fill your fields?